# Iterate through document and insert cross references using VBA

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, macros, cross-reference

I'm using mail merge in Word 2016, and then saving merged results as a PDF. In order not to break the hyperlinked table of contents in the merged document when I save as PDF, I have to build a table of contents in the merged results prior saving as PDF. This works so long as I remember to insert the table of contents AFTER merging. I've written a simple macro that does this for me.

```
Sub AddTableofContents()
    With ActiveDocument
        .TablesOfContents.Add Range:=Selection.Range, RightAlignPageNumbers:= _
            True, UseHeadingStyles:=True, UpperHeadingLevel:=1, _
            LowerHeadingLevel:=1, IncludePageNumbers:=True, AddedStyles:="", _
            UseHyperlinks:=True, HidePageNumbersInWeb:=True, UseOutlineLevels:= _
            True
        .TablesOfContents(1).TabLeader = wdTabLeaderDots
        .TablesOfContents.Format = wdIndexIndent
    End With

End Sub
```

The issue I'm having is I have a series of hyperlinks back to the table of contents that break when I save the merged results as a PDF. The only work around I've found is to insert cross references, and then save as PDF. I'd like to do that programmatically, for instance in a for next loop since there are quite a few instances that need to be inserted **before** converting to PDF.

Ideally, this is what I'd like it to do:
1. Find the text "Click to Return to Table of Contents"
2. Select the text "Table of Contents"
3. Insert a cross reference

I'm getting pretty close:

```
    Selection.InsertCrossReference ReferenceType:="Bookmark", ReferenceKind:= _
        wdContentText, ReferenceItem:="TableofContents", InsertAsHyperlink:=True, _
         IncludePosition:=False, SeparateNumbers:=False, SeparatorString:=" "
    Selection.HomeKey Unit:=wdLine
```

How do I get it to find the next text, and the next, looping through the document until there are no more instances?

Edit replace doesn't seem to do it for me.

Ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to find *one text*, but replace part of it, you need something like this:

```
Sub inserttocrefs()
Const FindText As String = "Click to Return to Table of Contents"
Const MarkText As String = "Table of Contents"
Dim markTextPosition As Integer
Dim r As Word.Range
markTextPosition = InStr(1, FindText, MarkText)
Set r = ActiveDocument.Content
With r.Find
  .ClearFormatting
  ' you may need other initialization stuff
  .Text = FindText
  .MatchCase = False ' or true if you need that
  .Forward = True
  .Wrap = wdFindStop
  While .Execute
    r.Start = r.Start + markTextPosition - 1
    r.End = r.Start + Len(MarkText) ' redundant in your example
    r.InsertCrossReference _
      referencetype:="Bookmark", _
      referencekind:=WdReferenceKind.wdContentText, _
      referenceitem:="TableofContents", _
      insertashyperlink:=True
    r.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    r.End = ActiveDocument.Content.End
  Wend
End With
Set r = Nothing
End Sub
```

For that to achieve what you need, the bookmark "TableofContents" would need to "cover" a piece of text that says "Table of Contents"